# Will scribe-java work fine in appengine sandbox

Tags: google-app-engine, scribe

Am developing an app in AppEngine and experimenting OAuth where i came across scribe-java [1] which seems to be easy and good and am planning to use the same.

Will it play in appengine (i.e. with given JRE whitelist)? Any one using it with success?
I didn't see it listed in [2] and also googling on the same didn't give me direct answers.

Thanks for your reply.

[1] https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java 
[2] http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used scribe with Google AppEngine successfully many times.

Scribe uses `java.net.HttpURLConnection` which Google AppEngine supports, so there's no problem there.

Thanks for noticing that's not listed on the GAE page, will try to see if I can get Google guys to include it :)

Comment: Thanks Pablo. And thanks again for such a nice library. Also would be great if you could update scribe-java doc to reflect this info. May be its there and i overlooked..

Comment: @Pablo is there a detailed explanation on how to oAuth enable my own Google Apps Engine application? All the examples in your repo are for authenticating against someone elses service? I want to auth against my app. I have command line programs that work, but I need to be able to auth a web client ( html/javascript ). Any advice?